# add a triangle icon to the div opening and closing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the code where  onclick of the link, i am opening and closing the div

here is the code

```
<div id="opendialog" style="display:none;">
      <div style="width:100%;height:200px;background:grey;"></div>
    </div>
```

the function

```
function openx() {
      var x= document.getElementById("opendialog");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

it works well but how can i add a traingle to the link when clicked it should show a traingle to the div, trying in a way that if the screen is small or bigger, the traingle should be placed properly under the link when clicked and should not be a problem

here is the html i have

```
<div onclick="openx()">+ Add <div>
```

Comment: You might want to consider controlling the visibility and caret/triangle style via CSS, and toggle it with JavaScript. Rather than doing all via JS.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?   You just redo what you already have but the div id might be "linktriangle" instead of "opendialog"  Add a `<div style='display:none' id="linktriangle">triangle</div>` inside the "link", then use the same code you have but different id.   It would be easier/cleaner using a jquery event instead of onclick (as tagged jquery, even though you're not using jquery)

Comment: i am having trouble adding the traingle to it and concerned about how will it stay on its position once the screen is resized

Comment: You might like to target your question in that direction.  As it is, it seems overly concentrated on the opendialog part, which seems to be irrelevant to what you actually want/need:  *trying in a way that if the screen is small or bigger, the triangle should be placed properly under the link*

Comment: yeah about that but i think it should be answered in this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use font-awesome icon for triangle up and down. You just need to add and remove class accordingly.

```js
function openx() {
      var x= document.getElementById("opendialog");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myIcon").innerHTML = "➖";
      } else {
      document.getElementById("myIcon").innerHTML = "➕";
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
#myIcon {
margin-bottom: 3px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

#myIcon:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="openx()"><div id="myIcon">➕</div><div>

<div id="opendialog" style="display:none;">
      <div style="width:100%;height:200px;background:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of font-awesome, can' i use a div which is traingle based, because using font awesome, i had to export a whole library, i can create a traingle div and use it, will it be responsive and will it always be under the link even when the screen moves or resizes

Comment: @Neeza Yes you can use div also. I have edited the code you can have a look. Please tick if you got the answer.

Comment: Using `div` for interactive element might become an accessibility concern. I'd suggest you use a `button` element instead.

Comment: i did the change you mentioned, but it is not appearing under the link, it is appearing  just  on the side of the link, here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/43SSJrqB3b51

Comment: it should be under the _ plus and should appear only when clicked

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your question. Which link you are talking about?

Comment: my mistake i should have added that in code, missed it : `<div onclick="openx()">+ Add <div>`, i also edited my question

Comment: I have made the changes that you said. Take a look